# Unhandled error event in node.js and express app

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I was following along to this tutorial on "Authentication Using PassportJS" at [this blog](http://danialk.github.io/blog/2013/02/23/authentication-using-passportjs/)

And downloaded the files from his repo at https://github.com/DanialK/PassportJS-Authentication . And I intalled the packages that the terminal instructed me to. Then I attempted to run the app again but got this

```
connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
Express server listening on port 3000

events.js:66
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
    at Server.connect.connectionPool.on.server._serverState (/Users/juangallardo/Desktop/PassportJS-Authentication-master/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:540:74)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:115:20)
    at connection.on._self._poolState (/Users/juangallardo/Desktop/PassportJS-Authentication-master/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:140:15)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:91:17)
    at Socket.errorHandler (/Users/juangallardo/Desktop/PassportJS-Authentication-master/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:478:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:17)
    at Socket._destroy.self.errorEmitted (net.js:335:14)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not have MongoDB running

I found that "issue" [discussed on GitHub](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/node-angular/issues/6)

Then got the instructions to install and run mongo from [this tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)

```
brew install mongodb
```

Then you simply start the mongo server from the terminal with

```
mongod
```

Then back in your project just start the app with

```
node app.js
```